# Unexpected behavior of FullSimplify with integers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integral

I executed this command in Mathematica

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Sin[x] Sin[k x ], {x, 0, Pi}], Element[k, Integers]]
```

and got 0. However, if I execute the same command with k=1.

```
Integrate[Sin[x] Sin[k x] /. {k -> 1}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

I get the correct answer, Pi/2. Is this normal?
I would expected a conditional based on k=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's a flaw

The integral:

```
Integrate[Sin[x] Sin[k x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

evaluates to:

```
-(Sin[k \[Pi]]/(-1 + k^2))
```

If you do `Simplify[%, Element[k,Integers]]`, it will assume `Sin[k \[Pi]]` being zero. The **flaw** is, `Simplify` will assume `0` multiplies any non-directly-zero symbol being reduced to `0`, even if could be undefined:

```
0 / x (*Evaluates to 0*)
ReleaseHold[Hold[0 / x] /. x->0] (*boom*)
```

This is explained in detail within *Possible Issues* section of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html?q=Simplify).

All of above applies to `FullSimplify`